# Split Time into 3 Variables

Tags: php, datetime

I have a time "7:00 am" that I need to split into `$hour`, `$min`, `$ampm`. Is there an easy way that I can split this in to 3 variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$yourtime = "7:00 am";
preg_match("/([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}) ([a-zA-Z]+)/", $yourtime, $match);
$hour = $match[1];
$min = $match[2];
$ampm = $match[3];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$a      = preg_split('/[: ]/', '7:00 am');
$hour   = $a[0][0];
$minute = $a[1][0];
$ampm   = $a[2][0];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$time = '7:00 am';
list ($time, $ampm) = explode(' ', $time);
list ($hour, $min) = explode(':', $time);
```

Comment: @genesis Sure. But there's often many ways to solve a problem, right?

Answer (score 3):

```
sscanf( "7:00 am", "%d:%d %s", $hour, $min, $ampm );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = '7:00 am';
$hour = date("g",$time);
$min = date("i",$time);
$ampm = date("a",$time);
```

http://php.net/manual/function.date.php

Comment: i like you using time functions rather than just cutting up the string, but don't you need to do `mktime` on the string first?  sorry if im wrong, its been a little bit

Comment: The way the question is asked I wasn't sure if the OP had a string, or had an actual time object. I figured if OP was asking this (s)he is probably new to php and should probably be using the simplest, most direct route, and should review the docs to see why. Cutting strings and preg matching like some of the other answers is not beginner level stuff so OP should at least get to see that there are simpler solutions out there. Final Thought: preg_match seems like sandblasting a saltine for a solution to this, and is probably requiring a lot more processing than the problem really needs.

Comment: probably not, been awhile since I used php, but it's easy to convert time strings to timestamps with strtotime. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php