# How to split time value in PHP?

Tags: php

I have these time value from HTML form using timepicker js.

I want to split the value into three (3) variables which is $hour, $minute and $period.

The problem is I can't split **'AM'** or **'PM'** value into another variable.

**$minute** hold the value "00 PM". I want AM or PM store into another variable call **$period**

What I have done so far as code below.

**Time.php**

```
<?php

// $btArray           = explode(':', $_POST['app_time']);    

$btArray              = explode(':', '11:00 PM');
$hour                 = strlen(trim($btArray[0])) > 1 ? trim($btArray[0]) : '0' . trim($btArray[0]);
$minute               = trim($btArray[1]);
$period               = trim($btArray[2]);


$query = "UPDATE TABLE
SET 
                BOOK_TIME       = '" . $hour . ":" . $minute . "', 
                TIME_PERIOD     = '" . $period ."'

WHERE 
                TRACK_NUM       = ''
";
?>
```

My goal is to split the value so I can store it into database.

Appreciate if someone can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I see two major problems here.  First, probably the most important, is that concatenating a query the way you are doing in leaves your code prone to SQL injection attacks.  That aside, why are you storing hours, minutes, and seconds separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Time into 3 Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378792/split-time-into-3-variables)

Comment: That's the way of previous developer design the database. I also don't agree but the system already live. I have no choice but to follow.

Comment: Thanks . @MadhuriPatel . your suggestion works like a charm

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . Its just a question. Of course in production i add security on my coding :) . Thanks for your advice btw.

Answer (score 1):

```
$btArray= "7:00 am";
preg_match("/([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}) ([a-zA-Z]+)/", $btArray, $match);
$hour = $match[1];
$min = $match[2];
$period = $match[3];

$query = "UPDATE TABLE
              SET 
                BOOK_TIME       = '" . $hour . ":" . $minute . "', 
                TIME_PERIOD     = '" . $period ."'
              WHERE 
                TRACK_NUM       = ''
";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest to use [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function as the parameters like: hour, minute, seconds are fixed.

First need to check whether the string length of 8.

Then, get parameters depending upon their positions.

If your date format is constant.

```
<?php
$str = '11:00 PM';
if (strlen($str) == 8) {
 $hour = substr($str, 0, 2);
 $minute = substr($str, 3, 2);
 $period = substr($str, 6, 2);
}
echo '<pre>';print_r('Hour: '. $hour);echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>';print_r('Minute: '. $minute);echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>';print_r('AM/PM: '. $period);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Hour: 11
Minute: 00
AM/PM: PM
```

[Working Demo:](https://3v4l.org/m7Rhn)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$time = '11:00 PM';
//first remove right two char
$period = substr($time, -2, 2);
//remove that string from main string
$newTime = str_replace($period, "", $time);
//convert remaining string to array
$btArray = explode(':', $newTime);
//check hour string length and concate 0
$hour = (strlen($btArray[0]) > 1) ? $btArray[0] : '0'.$btArray[0];
$mint = $btArray[1];
echo $hour.'<pre>';
echo $mint.'<pre>';
echo $period.'<pre>';
die;
```

Output:

```
11
00
PM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code for your desire output.

```
$btArray = explode(':', '11:00 PM');
$hour = strlen(trim($btArray[0])) > 1 ? trim($btArray[0]) : '0' . trim($btArray[0]);
$minute_period_array = explode(' ', $btArray[1]);
$minute = trim($minute_period_array[0]);
$period = trim($minute_period_array[1]);
echo 'Hour - ' . $hour . '<br/>';
echo 'Minute - ' . $minute . '<br/>';
echo 'Period - ' . $period . '<br/>';
```

**Output :**

```
Hour - 11
Minute - 00
Period - PM
```

Answer (score -1):

If you will get the input value always in the same format, you can go this way:

```
$input = '8:05 PM';
list($hour, $minute, $period) = explode(' ', str_replace(':', ' ', $input), 3);

// And then clean the variables

$hour = str_pad($hour, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$minute = str_pad($minute, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$period = strtoupper(trim($period));

// $hour -> 08, $minute -> 05, $period -> PM
```